# R and igraph: propagate a node information in a dendrogram like graph

Tags: r, data.table, igraph

I would like to propagate an information in a network/graph having a dendrogram structure. The data represent the administrative structure of an industry. I have various administrative levels, and various elements within these levels.
I have an info that I have for some elements at a given level, that I would like to propagate to lower levels. I actually do not have the info of the level, I only have the relation between one element and its parent.

Here is an example to illustrate:

```
library(data.table)
library(igraph)
library(ggraph)

vertex <- data.table(ID = c("main","1_1","1_2","2_1","2_2","2_3","2_4","3_1","3_2","3_3","3_4"),
                     info = c(NA,"plouf","plof",NA,NA,"truc",NA,NA,NA,NA,NA),
                     level = c("top",1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3))

edges <- data.table(to = c("main","main","1_1","1_1","1_2","1_2","2_1","2_1","2_3","2_3"),
                    from = c("1_1","1_2","2_1","2_2","2_3","2_4","3_1","3_2","3_3","3_4"))

g <- graph_from_data_frame(d = edges,vertices = vertex,directed = T)

ggraph(g, layout = 'dendrogram') + 
  geom_edge_elbow()+
  geom_node_point(aes(color = level),size = 3)+
  geom_node_text(aes(label = name),nudge_y = .1)+
  geom_node_label(aes(label = info),nudge_x = 1)
```

[image]

Each `ID` is one element. I indicate the level for illustrative purpose, but I do not have this info. I want to propagate the `info` in the `vertex` table to the lower levels where it is missing.

As I don't have the level information in the `vertex` table, I need to retrieve from the structure where/in which direction to propagate the information.

The expected outcome should be:

```
vertex_final <- data.table(ID = c("main","1_1","1_2","2_1","2_2","2_3","2_4","3_1","3_2","3_3","3_4"),
                     info = c(NA,"plouf","plof","plouf","plouf","truc","plof","plouf","plouf","truc","truc"))

      ID  info
 1: main  <NA>
 2:  1_1 plouf
 3:  1_2  plof
 4:  2_1 plouf
 5:  2_2 plouf
 6:  2_3  truc
 7:  2_4  plof
 8:  3_1 plouf
 9:  3_2 plouf
10:  3_3  truc
11:  3_4  truc
```

[image]

I actually do not know how to proceed, but I am quite sure this is not that complicated. Cam someone help ? Thanks!

Comment: Could an info change ? LIke `plouf` become `truc` ?

Comment: no, the info should be propagated down until it meets a non-missing info

Answer (score 0):

This piece of code iterates through the tree to replacer a `NA` value with the parent's one. It assumes that you have an `info` value for the first child.

```
for (i in edges$from ) { 
  if ( is.na(vertex[ID == i, info])) {
    vertex[ID == i]$info <- vertex[ID == edges[from == i, to], info]
  }
}
> vertex
      ID  info level
 1: main  <NA>   top
 2:  1_1 plouf     1
 3:  1_2  plof     1
 4:  2_1 plouf     2
 5:  2_2 plouf     2
 6:  2_3  truc     2
 7:  2_4  plof     2
 8:  3_1 plouf     3
 9:  3_2 plouf     3
10:  3_3  truc     3
11:  3_4  truc     3
```

If a value `info` is `NA` for node `i`, it takes the `ID` of the parent of `i` in `edges` and uses it in the `vertex` table to get the `info` value of the parent.

Comment: How do I know that `3_3` comes from the second level ?

Comment: First  number `3` is the level. 3-1 = 2. Second number if the number of the node in the level.

Comment: In my real dataset I do not have this info. The name I gave are for illustrative purpose.

Comment: @denis my badI just realised I completely ignored `edges`, there is totally a way to porpagate the info, let write that.

Comment: nope, it does not work. It works only in this example because of the order of the edge data.frame, and because the nodes with info are not far from the others. If you loop start with `3_1` for example, it does not work. I want a generic answer using the graph structure, so based on `g`